# How to include blade template when it inside another element

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a layout contain header include navbar and slider image.

My `views` folder has structure like:

```
+ layouts
   - index.blade.php
   - master.blade.php

+ posts
   - list.blade.php

+ partials
   - navbar.blade.php
   - footer.blade.php
```

Note:

`+` is `a folder`.

`-` is `blade template file`

Normally, in the `master.blade.php` is declare css/js file, include navbar and footer blade template.

But navbar inside a `div#home`, this element contains navbar and slider.

```
<section id="home">
    @include('partials.navbar')
    <!-- slider start -->
    @yield('slider_images')
    <!-- slider end -->
</section>
```

So, I can't split navbar to insert into `master.blade.php`. You can see `master.blade.php` like:

```
//add some js and css.
<body>

  @yield('content')

  @include('partials.footer')

</body>
```

I don't add line: `@include('partials.navbar')` because it include a slide.

The temporary solution is to add it into `index.blade.php`.

But the problem is: I have a child page, it `@extends('layouts.master')`. But the `layout.master` don't have contained `partials.navbar`. It only needs navbar and footer, don't need the slider.

Have any method to do this without change structure of HTML file.

Answer (score 2):

You could pas a variable to the blade template:

```
@include('partials.navbar', ['slider' => true])
```

and then in the navbar you could check for that variable

```
@if(isset($slider) && $slider === true)
    <!-- slider start -->
    @yield('slider_images')
    <!-- slider end -->
@endif
```

in that way the slider will be shown only when the slider variable is set to true